# PostgreSQL relation doesn't exist (Python)

Tags: python, json, postgresql, twitter, psycopg2

I created a database in psql and in it, created a table called "tweet".

```
CREATE TABLE tweet 
 ( tid CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL, DATA json, 
   CONSTRAINT tid_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tid) );
```

Then when I use

```
SELECT * FROM tweet;
```

in the psql window it works and shows an empty table.

Now I have a python script that takes JSON data and is loading it into this table.

```
conn_string = "host='localhost' port=5432 dbname='tweetsql' user='tweetsql' password='tweetsql'"

conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

That sets up the connection and I don't think it had any issues.
Now I have some logic to read in the JSON file and then to add it in, I say:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet (tid, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (cur_tweet['id'], json.dumps(cur_tweet, cls=DecimalEncoder), ))
```

But this always says that the relation tweet doesn't exist. Am I missing something here? Is there an issue with my connection or can my script somehow not see the table? For reference I'm using psycopg2 for the connection.

EDIT: I updated the DDL to include a transaction I could commit but that didn't fix it either. Is it a schema issue?

This is what I did regarding the table creation to commit:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE tweet 
 ( tid CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL, DATA json, 
   CONSTRAINT tid_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tid) );
COMMIT;
```

EDIT 2: I'm posting some code here...

```
import psycopg2
import json 
import decimal 
import os 
import ctypes 

conn_string = "host='localhost' port=5432 dbname='tweetsql' user='tweetsql' password='tweetsql'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tweet (tid CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL, DATA json, CONSTRAINT tid_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tid) );")
cur.commit() 


for file in os.listdir(path):    
    if not is_hidden(file):     
        with open(path+file, encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            tweets = json.load(json_file, parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
            for cur_tweet in tweets:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet (tid, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (cur_tweet['id'], json.dumps(cur_tweet, cls=DecimalEncoder), ))

cur.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: `in the psql window it works and shows an empty table.` But (without rows) it **is** an empty table! [BTW there should be a `;` after the create table DDL]

Comment: Right, I was saying that in psql window that the relation existed (it should be empty since I didn't add data - I was just checking to make sure creation worked). And sorry I did have the colon when I wrote the command I just forgot it here.

Comment: Did you commit (in the "psql window") ?

Comment: Oh, I thought if I used CREATE TABLE that it would already be in there (sorry I'm new to this). How do I commit the new table? When I try to just say COMMIT; it just says that no transactions are in progress.

Comment: Not only DML, but also DDL is part of a transaction. Other sessions cannot *see* uncommitted transactions.[BTW: nex time, please add complete working code to your question, including the needed `import psycopg2, json`, and some data.]

Comment: How do I commit a new table? Just COMMIT; ? And I'll update with code. Thanks. I tried just COMMIT; and it just says that htere aren't any transactions and the python code still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not committing the table creation, and, (I'm assuming; not seeing your complete code) you're starting a new connection via psycopg2 each time.  You need to commit right after the table creation, and *not* in a new connection, as each connection is its own implicit transaction.  So, your code flow should be something like this:

1. connect to the db
2. create the table using the cursor
3. fill the table
4. commit and disconnect from db.

Or, if you must separate creation from filling, just commit and disconnect after (2) and then reconnect before (3).

Comment: Ah, I was creating table in psql but using the python code to load the data in (so it was trying to create a connection after the table was there). Let me try this.

Comment: psql (with default settings) auto-commits; so, creating a table there and then filling it via code, should work.   Please accept the answer and upvote if it does work for you. :-)

Comment: I put an example of my code there. This still throws the same error I had earlier. I think I followed what you said right?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it looks fine.  Please paste the full exact error.

Comment: Actually shoot, I see it's a different error. It says: "psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tid_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (tid)=(776571048946831400) already exists."

Comment: Guess that's because I have multiple tweets from the same user. Shoot.

Comment: Right. So, I imagine the error changed fro what you were originally seeing to what you saw after applying the suggested flow.

Comment: Yeah. I give up. I'm going to try to make this project work with DynamoDB instead but that's a nightmare for me haha. Thanks for sorting out the connection issue though! :)

Comment: Never give up! :) If you're getting a duplicate key error on the tid column, which, from my quick search is supposed to be a unique tweet (not just user id), it just means you've already loaded the same exact tweet (not just one from the same user).  Maybe during development you've re-tried loading the same file multiple times? So, either execute a "truncate tweet" in psql to clear it, and try again, or, if you're using Postgresql >= 9.5, add this to the end your insert clause "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" which will skip inserting duplicates. Good luck and please upvote. :)